# How to get all local images and load it into an array in swift

Tags: ios, swift3

i haven't found yet any solution to load and get all gallery images.  so any help ? 
i tried with picker controller but it doesn't give me a way to get all images without selecting any of them . [the collection view look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUx1f.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `AVFoundation` and `Photos framework`.

Visit  [Photos framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html), and download sample source code.